# Out of band messaging

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I have to implement duplex binding out of band messages in my project. Are there are any resources that give example of how to implement out of band duplex binding messages in c#?

Comment: What is `out of band messages`?

Comment: Normally messages are sent/received on request/response basis. Out of band messages are where there is no request and you send it to the client or client can response the message without any request.